# how to solve Trying to get property 'bids' of non-object error

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatables

I want to display data from bid table in a form of datatable. But I get this error
 "Trying to get property 'bids' of non-object" if it doesn't have bids.The bids model is connected to auction model and the auction model is connected to media site model. How to make it display blank record if it doesn't have data.

Here is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Auction;
use App\Bid;
use App\User;
use App\Media;
use App\MediaSite;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class MediaSiteController extends Controller
{
public function show(MediaSite $mediaSite)
{
$auction = $mediaSite->auction;
$bids = $auction->bids;


return view('admin.media-site.show', ['mediaSite' => $mediaSite,'auction' => $auction], compact('auction'));
    }
```

My view:

```
<body>
<div id="datatable-bid"></div>
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var datatableBid = $('#datatable-bid').mDatatable({

// datasource definition
data: {
type: 'local',
source: {!! json_encode($auction->bids) !!},
pageSize: 10
},

// layout definition
layout: {
theme: 'default', // datatable theme
class: '', // custom wrapper class
scroll: false, 

footer: false // display/hide footer
},

// column sorting
sortable: true,

pagination: true,

search: {
input: $('#panel-search')
},

// columns definition
columns: [
{

field: "price",
title: "Price",
}, {

field: "month",
title: "Month",
},{

field: "user_id",
title: "User Id",
}
]
});

</script>
```

Here is my error:
[Trying to get property 'bids' of non-object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4EHX.png)

Comment: so `$mediaSite->auction` is not returning what you think it is?

Comment: it returns correctly if the data exist in database but gives error for when there is not data. I want to return "no records" if there is no data.

Comment: So detect if it exists before you try to read if....

Comment: i am not sure how to do that. I tried putting if else in my controller but it doesn't work

Comment: I am not a php dev so can not tell you how to fix the code.

Comment: This error shoots because your $auction is null. posted an answer mate.just have a look. It ll help

Answer (score 0):

place following after `$auction = $mediaSite->auction;`

```
if($auction){
$bids = $auction->bids;
}else{
//put following line or whatever you need to do if there is no data comes
$auction = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `show()` function make these changes

```
$auction = $mediaSite->auction;
if($auction) {
  $bids = $auction->bids;
} else {
  $bids = [];
}
// now send $bids to view along with $auction
// may be like this
// return view(..., compact($auction, $bids));
```

Then, in your view make this change

```
// datasource definition
data: {
type: 'local',
source: {!! json_encode($bids) !!},
pageSize: 10
},
```

See if this helps.